# Is there any use in caching very small objects?

Tags: java, android, caching

`TaggedLogger` has only a string field - `tag`.

```
public class TaggedLogger {

    private final String tag;

    public static TaggedLogger forInstance(Object instance) {
        return new TaggedLogger(getTagOfInstance(instance));
    }

    public static String getTagOfInstance(Object instance) {
        return getTagOfClass(instance.getClass());
    }

    public static TaggedLogger forClass(Class<?> someClass) {
        return new TaggedLogger(getTagOfClass(someClass));
    }

    public static String getTagOfClass(Class<?> someClass) {
        return someClass.getName();
    }

    public static TaggedLogger withTag(String tag) {
        return new TaggedLogger(tag);
    }

    private TaggedLogger(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public void debug(Object obj) {
        Log.d(getTag(), String.valueOf(obj));
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void exception(String message) {
        Log.e(getTag(), String.valueOf(message));
    }

    public void exception(Throwable exception) {
        Log.e(getTag(), String.valueOf(exception.getMessage()), exception);
    }

    public void exception(Throwable exception, String additionalMessage) {
        Log.e(getTag(), String.valueOf(exception.getMessage()), exception);
        Log.e(getTag(), String.valueOf(additionalMessage));
    }

    public void info(Object obj) {
        Log.i(getTag(), String.valueOf(obj.toString()));
    }

}
```

And `TaggedLoggers` is using to get cached (or create new and put in cache) `TaggedLogger` instances:

```
public class TaggedLoggers {

    public static final TaggedLogger GLOBAL = getCachedWithTag("GLOBAL");

    private static final Map<String,TaggedLogger> cache = new HashMap<String, TaggedLogger>();

    public static TaggedLogger getCachedForInstance(Object obj) {
        return getCachedWithTag(TaggedLogger.getTagOfInstance(obj));
    }

    public static TaggedLogger getCachedForClass(Class<?> someClass) {
        return getCachedWithTag(TaggedLogger.getTagOfClass(someClass));
    }

    public static TaggedLogger getCachedWithTag(String tag) {
        TaggedLogger logger = cache.get(tag);
        if (logger == null) {
            logger = TaggedLogger.withTag(tag);
            cache.put(tag, logger);
        }
        return logger;
    }

}
```

Is there any use in `TaggedLoggers` class?

Actually I often use `TaggedLogger` for logging using arguments as tags. I.e.:

```
public class FragmentUtils {
    public static void showMessage(Fragment fragment, String message, int toastDuration) {
        TaggedLoggers.getCachedForInstance(fragment).debug(message);
        Context context = fragment.getActivity();
        if (context == null) {
            return;
        }
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, toastDuration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

So, caching `TaggedLogger` instances actually helps me to avoid a lot of unnecessary instances.

But, should I to do so?

Comment: You forgot to ask yourself two important questions: Do I have a problem? Would implementing this help solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching of existing instances can help a lot or can kill performances.

When creating a new instance you have to consider two factors :

1. The time to setup the instance itself, that is allocate ram, initialize fields and execute the constructor
2. The time taken by the garbage collector to cleanup after the instance is not reachable anymore

This used to be a lot of time on older JVMs, not the garbage collector has been improved and usually creating and throwing away small instances is not a big problem as it was before, but still it has it's cost. Don't know exactly how much Android JVMs have been optimized.

In this case it depends on how often you create and throw away these instances, which you said is very often.

When instead reusing them, you have to consider two factors :

1. The time to lookup the existing instance, that is a map lookup
2. The ram that is kept full of actually unused instances

So, in this case, it depends on how many different instances you have. If you will have thousands of TaggedLogger's then looking up the map and keeping all that stuff in ram could hurt performances more than creating and throwing away.

If TaggedLoggers are around hundred(s), then probably better caching, if they go into thousands, then probably better to instantiate and throw away.

However, I would question wether you need a TaggerLogger. If you always have the tag String, can't you simply call the logger method or only have a (possibly even static) façade in front of it, instead of instances that contains only an information (the tag string) that you already have?

Comment: [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61682/taggedlogger-log-wrapper) I illustrated why I need this class.

Answer (score 0):

Creating and garbage collecting `TaggedLogger`s would be nearly free, so there's no real benefit to caching them, but since `TaggedLoggers` uses a `HashMap` instead of a `ConcurrentHashMap` there is the potential, if it is called from multiple threads, for difficult to debug problems up to and including an infinite loop if two threads try to resize the map larger at the same time.

It provides little if any benefit, creates additional complexity, and may create problems.

See also: [A Beautiful Race Condition](http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html)